# Can I still get a free genuine Windows 10 copy?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

So I got Windows 8 out of the box, upgraded for free to Windows 8.1,  then to Windows 10 (again for free). Then I installed Ubuntu, then went back to Windows 10 (cracked). I had a PC expert I know install Windows 10 cracked on my PC. Seems like he used this hack "AutoKMS" and it worked. But it seems like he got an unofficial version of the hack that had a "surprise" in it. If you know what I mean.
Windows Defender detected some Trojan I don't remember the name of so I deleted it. Then another Trojan came: Kaymunder.C. and I deleted that too. But for safety I wanna have a legit clean install.
I know that product keys can be reused and are saved in the motherboard. So... If I do a legitimate clean install is it gonna activate for free?

Comment: If the motherboard and major components are the same as when you first got the free upgrade then it should activate with no problems.

Comment: @Mokubai I was told that it's not possible because the Samsung "skin" of it isn't there anymore. It's true?

Comment: If it was the Windows 8 version that was "skinned" and then you got the free upgrade that was offered last year, then you should still have a digital entitlement to Windows 10. You can use the Microsoft Media Creation tool for Windows 10 to create a legitimate install disk.  I'd recommend doing it on a clean machine rather than the one with a prise.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "Id recommend doing it on a clean machine rather than the one with a prise"?

Comment: You mentioned that the version you had got instaleed had a "surprise" on it. I would consider that copy of Windows completely suspect and untrustworthy. Go to a **trusted** machine, go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and click the "download tool now" button to create a bootable USB or DVD that will give you a valid Windows installer

Comment: I Don't think it can corrupt the installation. I could try it on VirtualBox first. By the way, can a VM detect my product key?

Answer (score 1):

When you once install windows 10 and activate it, you can always for free install the same version of windows 10 that you previously activated on your computer and it will activate again.

There's a catch however, you need to make sure the hardware does not change.

Also, if windows does not activate, you may still be able to use your windows 8 key to activate windows, but if you have a windows 8 home key, you can obviously only activate a windows 10 home version.

Lastly, KMSpico is always found to be bad by windows defender, because they know very well what the program is supposed to do and want to scare away users with a false positive.

Comment: I scanned with MalwareBytes too and it detected something. So it's not only KMS itself.